# inserting a button inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

*Hi everyone, I would like to ask if it is possible to pass a button inside an object to be used once the object items are displayed? I was trying to do the following code but I am pretty sure its not the correct way as I got errors which say: Unexpected token <. Thanks a lot for your time*

```
array = [];
array.push({label: <input type="button" value="B"/> });
```

Comment: You can't mix HTML with Javascript. (Footnote: well… let's not get into JSX…). At the very least you want a *string* of HTML there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSX, you can use like so. But since you're using plain JS, you'll need to use quote:

```
array.push({label: '<input type="button" value="B"/>' });
```

Comment: this is correct but what if I would like to add an onclick function to that?

Comment: You can, how you did `value=""`. The same applies to onclick like `onclick="doSomething()"`

Comment: @jurgen Then you probably want to get into creating *DOM objects* programmatically using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Comment: one last question @BhojendraRauniyar. I am trying to do something like: var code = " "; onclick="code = 'B' ". is that possible?

Comment: @jurgen.s you can concatenate or use template string. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - So, in your case it would be: `\`<input type="button" value="B" onclick="code='B'" />\``

Answer (score 2):

You have to use quotes around the values which are strings. The values in the object is not a button. It is a string. When functions like `document.write` or `innerHTML` are passed these strings they render it as a button/HTML element

```js
array = [];
array.push({label:'<input type="button" value="B"/>' });
document.body.innerHTML=array[0].label
```

Comment: Correct in this case, however due to the question I assume the OP is not very familiar with JSON. Therefore it would be good to mention that a String value should  have quotes, since this does not have to be the case for ints, arrays, objects